# How can I find the limit of $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( 4x^{2}\sin ^{2}\left( \dfrac {2} {x}\right) \right)$ to infinity?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

The title basically tells everything. The result is 16 but I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** put $\frac{1}{x}=y$ and note that,

$$ \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint without words:

$$4x^2\sin^2\frac2x=16\left(\frac{\sin\frac2x}{\frac2x}\right)^2\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

Next time, please do add a few details of your attempt, else you won't get any reply here.